# How to choose static IO memory map for virtual memory on ARM

Tags: linux, kernel, arm

I am investigating how to port the Linux kernel to a new ARM platform. 
I noticed that some platform implementations have static mapping from a physical IO address to a virtual address in `map_io` function.

My question is how should I decide the "virtual" address in structure `map_desc`? Can I map a physical IO to arbitrary virtual memory? or are there some rules or good practice about it? I checked http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/arm/memory.txt , but did not find any answers.

Here are some examples of `map_desc` and `map_io`:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-versatile/versatile_dt.c#L45

```
 44 DT_MACHINE_START(VERSATILE_PB, "ARM-Versatile (Device Tree Support)")
 45         .map_io         = versatile_map_io,
 46         .init_early     = versatile_init_early,
 47         .init_machine   = versatile_dt_init,
 48         .dt_compat      = versatile_dt_match,
 49         .restart        = versatile_restart,
 50 MACHINE_END
```

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-versatile/core.c#L189

```
189 void __init versatile_map_io(void)
190 {
191         iotable_init(versatile_io_desc, ARRAY_SIZE(versatile_io_desc));
192 }

131 static struct map_desc versatile_io_desc[] __initdata __maybe_unused = {
132         {
133                 .virtual        =  IO_ADDRESS(VERSATILE_SYS_BASE),
134                 .pfn            = __phys_to_pfn(VERSATILE_SYS_BASE),
135                 .length         = SZ_4K,
136                 .type           = MT_DEVICE
137         }, {
```

Answer (score 1):

too long for a comment...

Not an expert but, since map_desc is for static mappings. It should be from system manuals. virtual is how the peripheral can be accessed from kernel virtual space, pfn (page frame number) is physical address by page units.

Thing is if you are in kernel space, you are using kernel virtual space mappings so even you want to access a certain physical address you need to have a mapping for that which can be one-to-one which I believe what you get out of map_desc.

Static mapping is map_desc, dynamic mapping is ioremap. So if you want to play with physical IO, ioremap is first thing if that doesn't work then for special cases map_desc.

[DMA-API-HOWTO](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) provides a good entry point to different kind of addresses mappings in Linux.

Comment: The background of this question is that I need to implement early printk macro: addruart, senduart, waituart;  The "addruart" macro needs the UART ports virtual address and physical address.  completely reply on map_io() to setup the mapping. physical memory is something I can find out from hardware manual, but virtual address is the thing I need to know to decide a value.

Comment: Just commenting on background part, that problem shouldn't be unique for you. boot loader doesn't help with early prints before uart re-initialization? for the virtual address part I guess then any low mem should do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The bootloader may did some UART hardware initialization, but code to put characters to UART hardware still relies on kernel's implementation.

Comment: auselen, you are right, ioremap should be just enough for me. And some correction of my previous comment about addruart for early printk: It does not use map_io to do VM mapping for UART port, the kernel boot up code will directly get VM address via addruart and do the mapping for us.